# How to save after applying the butterworth filter

Tags: matlab

I am taking in an audio file and applying butterworth filter. After filtering I want to re-save filtered file to another audio file called z.wav. how can i do this ?

```
a=audioread('a.wav');

[B,A] = butter(200,0.9);

audiowrite('z.wav',a,44100);
```

However, the above code doesnt work. It just saves a copy of `a.wav` file.

Comment: You haven't applied the filter anywhere. 
`a_filtered = filter(B,A,a);` 
Then use `audiowrite('z.wav',a_filtered,44100);`

Comment: @schvaba986 post it as an answer, as it is the answer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri You're right

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to filter your signal using `filter` function or `filtfilt`. Secondly before writing to the file, you  should normalize the samples.

Your code should be something like:

```
[x, fs] = audioread('a.wav');

[b,a] = butter(200,0.9);

y = filter(b,a,x);

y = 0.99*y/max(abs(y));

audiowrite('z.wav', y, fs);
```

Please keep in mind that your Butterworth has a very high order and it's magnitude and phase response are bit "disturbing"... You should definitely use lower orders.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't applied the filter operation anywhere. `[B,A] = butter(200,0.9);` gives you the filter coefficients. `a_filtered = filter(B,A,a);` does the filtering. Then you can use `audiowrite('z.wav',a_filtered,44100);` to save the result.